# How can I optimize my R code without using for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to optimize for-loop in my R-code.

Summary: I've a data frame (say, df) with 19 million rows including genes, and 2 columns('Chromosome' including corresponding chromosome, and 'Position' including corresponding position for each of those 19 mil genes). Now I want to create a new column 'chr_pos' being alternative name of each gene as Chromosome_Position. Example: a gene A located at chromosome 1, and position 123456 => Alternative name of the gene A would be 1_123456.

Here my code to do this:

```
for (i in nrow(df)){df$chr_pos[i] = paste0(df$Chromosome[i],"_",df$Position[i])}
```

I tried optimising using vectorisation but it's still ineffective.

Can this be optimised further?

Comment: `paste0` is already vectorized so you don't need `for` loop. `df$chr_pos <- paste0(df$Chromosome, "_",df$Position)` Or with `paste` `df$chr_pos <- paste(df$Chromosome,df$Position, sep = '_')`

Comment: Okay so I will run my code without for loop, but will it speed up my code well?

Comment: Oh, If I combine paste0 and apply, it will definitely speed up my code

Comment: You don't need `apply` here as well. Did you try the code in my comment above?

Comment: Oh wow, I am really sorry for not trying your solution first. It has done in several seconds. Thanks a lot. Please post your solution again to let me mark it !